# Caching lazy loaded collection in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Can we cache 2nd level in lazy loading

Example i have

"Student" has a "Subjects"

Subjects is a collection with onetomany relation

I am loading Subjects lazily in my service layer

Is it possible to cache lazily loaded subjects

Comment: I think when you call a collection which is annotated by lazy, then It will be automatically up to the cache! so the second call It will be get the Objects from the cache and not from the database

Comment: No during lazy fetch..if we are requesting child entity properties it hits the db when demanded